# Form to create ebean with complex parameters

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am fairly new to Play! 2 Framework and now i can't help myself with a problem anymore. I have a model entity **B** which has some attributes like id, name and a more complex attribute **A** with a @ManyToOne relationship. **A** itself has only some attributes like id and name.

A bit abstract but hopefully enough:

**A**:

```
@Entity
public class A extends Model {
    @Id 
    public Long id,
    @Required
    public String name;

    ...

    public static void create(Exam exam) {
            exam.save();
    }
}
```

**B**:

```
@Entity
public class B extends Model {
    @Id 
    public Long id,
    @Required
    public String name;
    @Required
    public A a;        

    ...

    public static void create(Exam exam) {
            exam.save();
    }
}
```

The controllers for the two models are very simple, again abstract:

```
public class BCtrl extends Controller {

    static Form<Exam> bForm = Form.form(B.class);

    public static Result bs() {
        return ok(views.html.b.render(B.all(), bForm));
    }

    public static Result newB() {
        Form<Exam> filledForm = bForm.bindFromRequest();
        List<Lecturer> lecturers = Lecturer.all();

        if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(views.html.b.render(Exam.all(), filledForm));
        }
        else {
            B.create(filledForm.get());
            return redirect(routes.BCtrl.bs());
        }
    }
}
```

And here comes my **Problem**. The Scala HTML file with the form to create a new **B**. Again abstract:

```
@(bs: List[B], bForm: Form[B])

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("B") {
    <ul>
        @for(b <- bs) {
            <li>
                @b.name
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    @helper.form(action = routes.ExamCtrl.newExam()) {
        @inputText(examForm("name"))
        @inputText(examForm("a"))
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    }
}
```

Every time I try to create a new B I get a validation error. What is the correct way to create an entity **B** with an association to **A**?

Answer (score 1):

Okay got it. Via

```
@inputText(examForm("a.id"))
```

I'm able to provide the id of object **A**. Using a HTML select element with all possible A's as options helps picking the right one!